# javascript on its own sheet

Tags: javascript, html

So my question is pretty simple, yet since im new to html and javascript, i need help.

So i have the following javascript code which is in my html code. i would like to have that function on its own seperate sheet . How do i call the function in my html sheet?

```
<script LANGUAGE="Javascript">
    var stampdays = new Array("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday");
    var stampmonths = new Array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December");
    var thedate = new Date();
    document.write(stampdays[thedate.getDay()] + ", " + stampmonths[thedate.getMonth()] + " " + thedate.getDate() + ", " + thedate.getFullYear());
</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to put the Javascript code into its own .js file?

Comment: yes, thats what i want. I want a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a file called `script.js`

script.js:

```
var stampdays = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var stampmonths = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var thedate = new Date();
document.write(stampdays[thedate.getDay()] + ", " + stampmonths[thedate.getMonth()] + " " + thedate.getDate() + ", " + thedate.getFullYear());
```

In your HTML, include this tag:

```
<script src="/path/to/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

You can include that tag anywhere in your HTML. Preferably right before the closing `</body>` tag.

On a side note, no need to use `new Array()`. Just use an array literal like I show in the code above.

On another side note, you probably don't want to use `document.write`. It's like 1997 style. You'll likely want to populate one of your HTML elements like so:

```
document.getElementById('myElementId').innerHTML = stampdays[...etc...getFullYear();
```

If you want to make that a function, you'd simply declare one:

```
function setDate(foo) {
    document.getElementById('myElementId').innerHTML = foo;
}
```

Then invoke it like `setDate(stampdays[...etc...getFullYear());`

Comment: thanks, it looks really helpful.
If i wanted to make it a function how would i rewrite it?
I want to display the date on a certain place in my html file

Comment: note that if you put the JS file at the bottom of your HTML, you'll need some sort of 'document ready' function to wait to execute the calls on your page until the JS file is finished loading.

Answer (score 0):

you can move everything inside the script tag(excluding the tag itself) into a new file (usually with extension js) and include that file in your html page. Its done like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to\script.js"> </script>
```

its better to use the `type` attribute than the `language` attribute

looking at your script i can see that you are using document.write outside any functions. Browsers typically execute the code in script tag as soon as they encounter one. You can have better control of the time of execution of the script if you put things inside a function

script.js

```
var stampdays = new Array( "Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday");
var stampmonths = new Array( "January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");

var writeDate = function () {
            var thedate = new Date();
            document.write(stampdays[ thedate.getDay()] + ", " + stampmonths[ thedate.getMonth()] + " " + thedate.getDate() + ", " + thedate.getFullYear()); 
            }
```

now you can call the writeDate function when needed.

```
<html> 
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="path-to\script.js"> </script>
</head>

<body>
  <script type="text/javascript" >
    writeDate();
  </script>

  <a href="#" onclick="writeDate()">Click me </a>

</body>
</html>
```

In the script.js file you just define the function writeDate, you dont execute it just yet. To actually run the code in the function you simply call the function as in writeDate() , here I have shown two ways.

- call the function inside another script tag (inside body), that will be executed when the browser is loading the html.
- a more typical example would be to execute that on some event; like in the example, i have defined something to be run when you click the  link